# engine speed rises but the vehicle lack power

Tags: ford, figo

I have 2011 Ford Figo with 117000 KM on Odo. But now i am having a strange problem, When i accelerate engine RPM rises but my car doesn't keep up and it takes some time to catch up with RPM. This problem increase as the engine get heated up. Could you lead me to its cause.

Comment: It sounds like your transmission is slipping. Do you have an automatic or manual transmission?

Comment: Nick, It is 5 gear manual transmission.

Answer (score 4):

If the vehicle is a manual transmission then is sounds like the clutch is on the way out. If its an automatic gearbox firstly you could check to see if the transmission fluid level is ok.

Either way I suggest you have the vehicles transmission inspected as there is likely a clutch issue that requires attention.

Comment: Hi, I too felt that this is clutch issue. Just wanted to run it through some experts. so i posted it hear.